# Read multiple integers (and save them in a file) with TensorFlow (Python)

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, save, mnist

Before I begin with explanation, this is the actual situation. Take a look at the image...

[image]

I have in order:

- MNIST_data: this folder contain [MNIST_data](https://github.com/lazyprogrammer/machine_learning_examples/tree/master/tensorflow/MNIST_data)
- series of images (digits) in .jpg format
- 2 .py files which will need to run the program. `predict_2.py` is the important one
- 3 model files (less important)

You can find the project I use [here](https://github.com/niektemme/tensorflow-mnist-predict).

So, this is what I need to do: once Tensorflow started (through CMD) with `predict_2.py` file, it will return (again, after CMD command) the number in the image I sent to it.

[image: one image for 1000 words]

So, I have the image (1), send command (2) TF do the recognition and the number is printed in CMD (3).

Now, as you can see, there are more numbers/integers/digits in the folder.
First question: how I can throw all of them ?
Second: After/Instead the output in CMD, how can I print/save them (all the numbers, not just one) in a file (example txt) ?

`predict_2.py` code is the follow:

```
"""
Predict a handwritten integer (MNIST expert).

Script requires
1) saved model (model2.ckpt file) in the same location as the script is run from.
(requried a model created in the MNIST expert tutorial)
2) one argument (png file location of a handwritten integer)

Documentation at:
http://niektemme.com/ @@to do
"""

#import modules
import sys
import tensorflow as tf
from PIL import Image, ImageFilter
import os
from datetime import datetime

def predictint(imvalue):
    """
    This function returns the predicted integer.
    The input is the pixel values from the imageprepare() function.
    """

    # Define the model (same as when creating the model file)
    x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 784])
    W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([784, 10]))
    b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([10]))

    def weight_variable(shape):
      initial = tf.truncated_normal(shape, stddev=0.1)
      return tf.Variable(initial)

    def bias_variable(shape):
      initial = tf.constant(0.1, shape=shape)
      return tf.Variable(initial)

    def conv2d(x, W):
      return tf.nn.conv2d(x, W, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')

    def max_pool_2x2(x):
      return tf.nn.max_pool(x, ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1], strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], padding='SAME')   

    W_conv1 = weight_variable([5, 5, 1, 32])
    b_conv1 = bias_variable([32])

    x_image = tf.reshape(x, [-1,28,28,1])
    h_conv1 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(x_image, W_conv1) + b_conv1)
    h_pool1 = max_pool_2x2(h_conv1)

    W_conv2 = weight_variable([5, 5, 32, 64])
    b_conv2 = bias_variable([64])

    h_conv2 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(h_pool1, W_conv2) + b_conv2)
    h_pool2 = max_pool_2x2(h_conv2)

    W_fc1 = weight_variable([7 * 7 * 64, 1024])
    b_fc1 = bias_variable([1024])

    h_pool2_flat = tf.reshape(h_pool2, [-1, 7*7*64])
    h_fc1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(h_pool2_flat, W_fc1) + b_fc1)

    keep_prob = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
    h_fc1_drop = tf.nn.dropout(h_fc1, keep_prob)

    W_fc2 = weight_variable([1024, 10])
    b_fc2 = bias_variable([10])

    y_conv=tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(h_fc1_drop, W_fc2) + b_fc2)

    init_op = tf.initialize_all_variables()
    saver = tf.train.Saver()

    """
    Load the model2.ckpt file
    file is stored in the same directory as this python script is started
    Use the model to predict the integer. Integer is returend as list.

    Based on the documentatoin at
    https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/how_tos/variables/index.html
    """
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(init_op)
        saver.restore(sess, "model2.ckpt")
        #print ("Model restored.")

        prediction=tf.argmax(y_conv,1)
        return prediction.eval(feed_dict={x: [imvalue],keep_prob: 1.0}, session=sess)


def imageprepare(argv):
    """
    This function returns the pixel values.
    The input is a png file location.
    """
    im = Image.open(argv).convert('L')
    width = float(im.size[0])
    height = float(im.size[1])
    newImage = Image.new('L', (28, 28), (255)) #creates white canvas of 28x28 pixels

    if width > height: #check which dimension is bigger
        #Width is bigger. Width becomes 20 pixels.
        nheight = int(round((20.0/width*height),0)) #resize height according to ratio width
        if (nheight == 0): #rare case but minimum is 1 pixel
            nheigth = 1  
        # resize and sharpen
        img = im.resize((20,nheight), Image.ANTIALIAS).filter(ImageFilter.SHARPEN)
        wtop = int(round(((28 - nheight)/2),0)) #caculate horizontal pozition
        newImage.paste(img, (4, wtop)) #paste resized image on white canvas
    else:
        #Height is bigger. Heigth becomes 20 pixels. 
        nwidth = int(round((20.0/height*width),0)) #resize width according to ratio height
        if (nwidth == 0): #rare case but minimum is 1 pixel
            nwidth = 1
         # resize and sharpen
        img = im.resize((nwidth,20), Image.ANTIALIAS).filter(ImageFilter.SHARPEN)
        wleft = int(round(((28 - nwidth)/2),0)) #caculate vertical pozition
        newImage.paste(img, (wleft, 4)) #paste resized image on white canvas

    #newImage.save("sample.png")

    tv = list(newImage.getdata()) #get pixel values

    #normalize pixels to 0 and 1. 0 is pure white, 1 is pure black.
    tva = [ (255-x)*1.0/255.0 for x in tv] 
    return tva
    #print(tva)

def main(argv):
    """
    Main function.
    """
    imvalue = imageprepare(argv)
    predint = predictint(imvalue)
    print (predint[0]) #first value in list

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(sys.argv[1])
```

What it need to be modified ?
I already have the code which can create automatically a file but it is empty (not even with the one detected digit in it).

Thanks in advance. For me it's not an easy task, it would be really, really, appreciate a help.

Comment: Found the solution...Will post soon..